# Infopath created form not editable

Tags: 2010, infopath, custom-form

I have created an InfoPath Edit form for a list in my SharePoint. And when published to SharePoint I am unable to edit the fields. All the fields look greyed out.

Can any one please assist me to get these fields edited?

[image]

Comment: Actually you can use the form. Is there any screen shot?

Comment: Hi, Screenshot is attached. the purpose is the users raise a request through this request form and save it, same will go and record in the lists of sharepoint.

Comment: Have you enabled browser compatible:http://office.microsoft.com/en-au/infopath-help/introduction-to-browser-compatible-form-templates-HA010169339.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Can you check the link for your InfoPath form using SharePointDesigner? It should be linked to editif.aspx, not dispif.aspx. I guess your list linked to dispif.aspx.

Comment: Can you please let me know how to check the link?